# Will exchanging a disk between two Dell Powervault MD1000s lead to data loss?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell, dell-perc

I have 2 servers, each with a Dell Powervault MD1000. I would like to take one disk from the first Powervault and relocate it to the second Powervault.

When I reboot the server, enter the `perc` configuration tool, I will add a new  virtual drive with the new physical disk. 
When I will initialize new virtual drive, can I lose the data ?

Because all tutorial I saw, I read this:

[image]

So if this process destroys all data, how can I add new disk in my Powervault without data loss?

Comment: Your image shows a RAID1 configuration. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes, on all tutorial I saw, any RAID show this message after clicked on OK button @Lenniey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move all the physical disks containing the virtual drive you want to move to the other server. You can then import the foreign configuration from those disks. You cannot simply move part of the disks. In this case the only thing you can do is lose the data.

Comment: Ok so if I understood correctly, if I have several virtual disks in my first powervault, and if I want to move one virtual disk, I have to move all physical disks (represents virtual disk I want to move) in second powervault. By doing this I am not losing data ? Sorry I'am totaly newbie in this domain @Michael Hampton

Comment: That's right for the most part. Just keep in mind that you're not guaranteed not to lose data - this is RAID, and RAID is not a backup in itself. Also, be sure to IMPORT the foreign configuration, do NOT "clear" it if you want to keep the data.

Comment: Ok so when I will in perc configuration, I will see menu for IMPORT the foreign configuration ?  @JimNim

Comment: @simon You should see a boot message which states: `Foreign configuration(s) found on adapter. Press any key to continue, or ’C’ to load the configuration utility or ’F’ to import foreign configuration(s) and continue.` You can press `F`, or you can also find the import option in the configuration utility's menus.